# Admin user account on windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 admin$ share access denied?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, windows-7

On my local network I have several windows 7 workstations and a Windows 2008 server. I have an account on each of my Windows 7 boxes that have the corresponding admin account on Windows 2008. When I try to access any of the admin shares on windows 2008 from windows 7 I get the login screen stating "Access Denied". I tried [this registry edit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vistacompatteam/archive/2006/09/22/766945.aspx) and a reboot, but it did not help.

So each Windows 7 box has an account named: AdminUser and that same account and password is on Windows 2008. I do not have a domain setup and each computer is in the workgroup: Workgroup. Including the server. Nothing special there. Is there another policy I need to setup to allow admin share access from Windows 7 on Windows 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I put the registry edit in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\UIPI` section instead of the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`